# how to create highcharts using data.csv file

Tags: zend-framework, highcharts

hi i have created a 'data.csv' file and now i want to create a highchart using the contents of that data.csv file. contents of my csv file are:

```
    2011-08-01 00:00:00,155
    2011-08-02 00:00:00,156
    2011-08-03 00:00:00,157
    2011-08-03 00:00:00,160
```

now i have written a javascript code to render the data and create a highchart, but it is showing nothing on my webpage. my code is

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'reading',
                x: -20      //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Date Measurement'
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'reading'
                }
            },
            series: []
    };

    $.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/myproject/public/data.csv', function(data) {

        // Split the lines using newline '\n' as delimiter
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {

            // split the line elements using comma ',' as delimiter
            var items = line.split(',');

            $.each (items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if(itemNo == 0)
                    options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                else if(itemNo > 0) {
                    var series = {
                            data: []
                    };
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                };
                options.series.push(series);
            });
            var chart = new HighCharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });

});
```

i don't know if i am doing something wrong. any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on your Javascript, specially if you want to do some Highcharts.

Steps are -

> Prepare your data.
>
> Create the options object.
>
> Render the chart.

The code below works if you put `data.csv` file in the same directory as your `html file`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    var c = [];
    var d = [];

    $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            c.push(items[0]);
            d.push(parseInt(items[1]));
        });
    });
        
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'reading'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date Measurement'
            },
            categories: c
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'reading'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: d
        }]
    };
        
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help, but still there is a problem. the webpage is showing a only the titles of xAxis and yAxis but no data. also i tried to check if the data is being read from file or not using alert(data). and i got two different outputs. in my zend studio, the alert window shows some uncaught exception saying "Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception with message Plugin by name 'HighchartsHelper' was not found in registry....." but when i type my url in webpage, the alert window shows proper data coming but no graph drawn.

Comment: I guess that it is because `new Highcharts` is being created outside the `$.get(...)` . It nees to be places begore `$.get(){}` is closed.

Comment: And also declare options before the `get` method